# How formal is "Я в вашем распоряжении"?

Tags: выражения

Is it formal and common in Russian?

"**я в вашем распоряжении**"

And exactly means: " I'm at your disposal " ?
Is there any other friendly sentence for informal situations?(common in daily conversation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it in daily conversations, just sometimes change "вашем" for "твоём", if you say it to one person you call "ты".

A more formal phrase is **я к вашим услугам**.

A less formal can be anything... But maybe more literal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is formal. And yes, as mentioned above, "Я к вашим услугам" is more common.
Yes, it exactly means "I am at your disposal".

A more friendly and informal alternative is "Всегда готов(-а) помочь" or "Всегда буду рад(-а) помочь".

Comment: or **можешь на меня расчитывать**

Answer (score 1):

This is a polite form from the old times, it is between formal and informal language. Just imagine a ball (or some cross-meeting, when not everyone knows each other), where young people from high society are friendly, but not informal.

So, in addition to its direct meaning, it becomes clear: no one will use 'я в вашем распоряжении' being in small group of close friends, but also no one will allow to say that at a business conversation. This is the middle of formal and informal ways to speak, a close mix of joke and truth. This can be used by good service staff, by members of team, or by politicians and businessmen enjoying something together to become familiar.

As a result, use 'я в вашем распоряжении', when you are ready to smile. When you pronounce this seriosly, it looks as work, rude service, way to earn money, as a wall for strangers.

Answer (score 0):

It is archaic expression. I would expect it to as humorous expression between friendly co-workers or friends.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly formal and would literally mean that you are subordinated to the one to whom you said it, in a very military-like style, as in "I am waiting orders".